# Javascript Ajax request fails in chrome because of adblock, what are my options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to run an ajax function

```
$.ajax({ url: etsyURL, dataType: 'jsonp', success: function(data) {
```

unfortunately in chrome on live it fails because of adblock

i'm using javascript/jquery because thats really all I know how to use, is there anyway to get around this issue?

Comment: You need to give some more details. What part is failing because of adblock?

Comment: I can not help you if that's all the information you're going to give. Is adblocker preventing you from making an ajax call to the url? Is the content that's being returned being hidden when you insert it into the page? If so what is that content. Nothing you have given so far is enough information to show any sort of problem much less find a solution.

Comment: adblocker causes the ajax call to fail. the ajax call does not get into the function, the dev tools responds with an error GET:"url". the ajax function is never called for it to hide anything. pausing adblock and refreshing the page allows the application to work

Comment: Adblock is not what is causing this. You need to provide more context on the rest of your code, and what your debugging has shown. Saying "adblock is preventing this generic line of code help please" is not going to get an answer.

Comment: @sgrif I also had the exact same issue. Some filter in EasyList is causing my Ajax request to fail.

Comment: You need to find what part of the URL triggers the adblock. That's pretty much everything adBlock is interested in. Can you post us the URL?

Comment: If the URL you are trying to to access belongs to an advertising company there is no way around it short of relaying through a server.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the "timeout" parameter on the ajax function to something like "5000". If the url is not responding within 5 seconds, the error handler is called.